# How could I type the image URL in div in data-src attribute, when I retrieve data from database (in ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

When I'm trying to get an image's URL with the attribute `data-src`, the image does not appear.

```
@foreach(var slide in Model.Slides)
{
    <div class="" data-src="~/images/home/slide/@slide.ImageURL">
    </div>
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show an image you can use:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/home/slide/" + @slide.ImageURL)" />
```

or

```
<img src="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/home/slide/" + @slide.ImageURL)" />
```

Comment: @Qusai Waleed AbuRayyan: I just want to note that the tilde ('~') is shortcut to the root of the application's virtual directory. So the `~` will be replaced to the value of `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath()`. [VirtualPathUtility Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.virtualpathutility?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

To show your image but maybe its null

```
@if(slide.ImageURl != null)
{
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/home/slide/" + @slide.ImageURL)" />
}
```